# salt master minion communication error in aws instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I have installed salt-master and minion on aws ec2 instances and configured cloud in the below format[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uyn8.png)

and i came up with the error like permission denied(publickey) can any one suggest me a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Owner of the key file must be the same user that start your services (salt-master/minion).
Otherwise OS won't allow you to read such file

The command is:
`chown this_maybe_salt_user /path/to/your/key`